# Websphere 6 webservice issue

Tags: web-services, websphere

We have just upgraded our webservice onto Websphere 6 from websphere 5.

A few clients have come back telling us of issues they are having.

Any clients that post SOAP directly to our service are getting issues such as

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: WSWS3047E: Error: Cannot
>   deserialize element request of bean
>   com.service.generic.query.GenericQuery_Request.

I tried the same soap request against our legacy Websphere 5 boxes and the correct responses are returned.

Do you think this may be an issue within websphere 6 or will we have to regenerate our webservice for Websphere 6?

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Damien

Comment: If this problem doesn't reach code you have written, it probably belongs on serverfault.

Comment: Hi

This problem does reach the code, i verified that before i posted on this forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely dealing with a library that got changed in the WebSphere.  What you can try to do is change the classloader policy to parent_last to see if it will fix it.